# Install more Python package/library to each cluster after creating an AWS EMR

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, amazon-emr, jupyterhub

I'm newly use Spark with PySpark on JupyterHub. I understand that before creating an EMR I can set the bootstrap to setup the environment in each cluster, like Python package/library. But If I already started the EMR, how can I install more Python package/library without restarting the EMR?

I searched and got some answer that I can install it via cell in Jupyterhub. For example,

```
%%spark
sc.install_pypi_package("matplotlib")
```

which I tried and got error

```
RuntimeError: install_pypi_packages can only use called when spark.pyspark.virtualenv.enabled is set to true
```

So I tried to set that config in `/usr/lib/spark/conf/spark-defaults.conf` on master cluster by adding this line into that file.

```
"spark.pyspark.virtualenv.enabled": "true"
```

But it doesn't work, JupyterHub still return an error.

So I want to know

1. What is best practice when I want to install more Python package/library to clusters when I already start the EMR?
2. How to config `"spark.pyspark.virtualenv.enabled": "true"` or can I set it up in software settings before creating the EMR?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: I think the correct way if its to be installed on all machines in the cluster is to get an admin to add the package as an bootstrap action: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/emr/latest/ManagementGuide/emr-plan-bootstrap.html

Comment: @chappers That's quite clear for me, thanks a lot!

Comment: I am seeing the same error on a SparkMagic(PySpark) kernel associated with an EMR cluster instance.

Answer (score 8):

I ran into the same issue. Here's what I had to insert as a new block above the `sc.install_pypi_package()` call.

```
%%configure -f
{
    "conf": {
        [other configs relevant to your situation],
        "spark.pyspark.python": "python3",
        "spark.pyspark.virtualenv.enabled": "true",
        "spark.pyspark.virtualenv.type":"native",
        "spark.pyspark.virtualenv.bin.path":"/usr/bin/virtualenv"
    }
}
```

Inspired by https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/big-data/install-python-libraries-on-a-running-cluster-with-emr-notebooks/